# Cookies and authentication for http requests on an iframe used as a chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, authentication, cookies, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I've created a webapp (in React) and I'd like to create a chrome extension that overlays a specific page of the webapp on every page I visit. My thought was to just build the page in my webapp and then use an iframe in the chrome extension to render that page. However, the page makes http requests to a server and uses an http only cookie for authentication. This doesn't seem to work with my iframe. Essentially I want a user that's logged in on my website be able to make authenticated http requests originating from the extension.

Is there a way to make this work? Or is this the wrong approach entirely and how should it be done? Thanks

Comment: https://crbug.com/40287010